# Real name of a Process

Tags: c#, winforms, process, system.diagnostics

I'm currently building a program that checks if a program is running or not. The goal is to also execute the Program if it is not already running.

The only problem is that I have to get the "real name" of a program. How do I find it?

Examples :
Text editor is called notepad

Vlc media player is called vlc

Microsoft Powerpoint is called  powerpnt
The real name i'm referring to is the process name of the task that im trying to get the status of.

OR is there a different way to execute a file after checking it is active?

So I build this:

```
    if (Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad").Length > 0 == true && cb1.Checked ==true )
            {
                lblsm.ForeColor = Color.Green;
                lblsm.Text = "online";
            }
            else if(Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad").Length > 0 == true && cb1.Checked == false)
            {
                lblsm.ForeColor = Color.Green;
                lblsm.Text = "online";
            }
            else if(Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad").Length > 0 == false && cb1.Checked == true)
            {
                Process.Start("notepad"); 
                lblsm.ForeColor = Color.Green;
                lblsm.Text = "online";
            }
            else
            {
                lblsm.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                lblsm.Text = "offline";
            }
```

//it appears that this way of calling a process only works with windows reinstalled programms and certain chosen ones...

Comment: What do you call "*real name*" ? Where do you found it without thinking C# ?

Comment: I did some research and found out about these 3 examples. The real name seems to be like the process name. But i can't figure out how and where to get it. I tried  many different variants but they all were not found ( wrong)

Comment: That's the *real name* of a Process. Usually, the executable name. PowerPoint's executable name is `POWERPNT.EXE`. You can strip the `.exe` part. You probably mean *how do I get the Path of the executable*. -- BTW, call `Process.GetProcessesByName()` just **once**, not for each condition you're testing. Also, those `== true` and `== false` are... Just, e.g., `If ([Something].Length > 0 && !cb1.Checked)`

Answer (score 0):

Time to answer my own question.

If you want to start a process you don't need the "real name" (which is the process name as correctly pointed out by Jimi in the comments).

In the case of

```
Process.Start("add Path in here");
```

But if you want to check if a process is already running you have to use the process name.
In the case of

```
Process.GetProcessesByName("add the executable name in here");
```

In some cases, you have to use the .exe in others you don't. It Depends on each program although I don't understand why.

If you want to find out the process name just open the task manager and open the detailed version. Then right-click on the top and choose the process name option. then it will show you the process name. You can also go to Github:https://github.com/yibn2008/find-process

and download this Users Process finder.